# Why is Rico surprised by Sonny expanding scope from Yero to Montoya?

Tags: plot-explanation, miami-vice-2006

During the second meeting with Fujiyama in *Miami Vice* (2006), Sonny asks for the undercover investigation to focus on Montoya instead of Yero's crew and gets aggressive. Rico looks surprised, although he aligns with Sonny.

What disturbs him: Sonny's initiative or Sonny's attitude?